# JSON using PHP to get selected values

Tags: php, json

Been looking thru stackoverflow about this so I did try to get this correct. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestions?

```
 <?php
    $string = '{
    "status": "success",
    "th_size": "small",
    "users": [
        {
            "user_id": 159826,
            "username": "WillBeUsed",
            "online": true,
            "is_away": false,
            "access": "public",
            "render_info": {
                "profile_url": "/person1",
                "profile_image": "11e5a496f13366a0c4ce000403aa862",
                "language": "english",
                "chat": "ready"
            },
            "new": false,
            "back": false
        }
    ],
    "online_count": 1
}';
    $result = json_decode($string, true);

//echo $result['status']; // This works
echo $result->users[0]->render_info->profile_url; // This don't work
    ?>
```

Comment: You should have done var_dump($result) to check whether the result is an object or an assosciative array. You would have saved a lot of time...

Comment: Thx Girish. I'll keep it in mind next time. :D Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't look hard enough. The PHP manual clearly states the parameters for `json_decode`:

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] );
```

By passing the second parameter as `true` you are telling it to give you back an associative array (not an object), so you need to access it like this:

```
$result['users'][0]['render_info']['profile_url'];
```

Comment: Ahhh.. Right, see it now. Thank you for taking time to reply. Works perfect. :)